# Javascript hover effect removes pre defined style

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I am using a [tutorial from Imar Spaanjaars' web site](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?quickdoc=312) to make an entire table row clickable and have a hover effect on it also. Once the user hovers over the table row it removes the pre defined background color for that row. I want to make it so that way it does not overwrite this style. How might I do that?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ChangeColor(tableRow, highLight)
    {
    if (highLight)
    {
      tableRow.style.backgroundColor = '#dcfac9';
    }
    else
    {
      tableRow.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    }
  }

  function DoNav(theUrl)
  {
  document.location.href = theUrl;
  }
  </script>
```

If you have any better suggestions to accomplish this task I would love to hear them!

My tr tag has a bgcolor tag in it that is set by my php if that specific piece of mail has been read or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the original background color is specified via a stylesheet or (as in your case) a legacy `bgcolor` attribute, then you can just clear out the style on the element when you're done, and it'll revert:

```
function ChangeColor(tableRow, highLight)
{
  if (highLight)
  {
    tableRow.style.backgroundColor = '#dcfac9';
  }
  else
  {
    tableRow.style.backgroundColor = '';
  }
}
```

That said, you'd probably be better off using a CSS class and associated rules to represent the highlighted state of the row and add/remove that as you like:

```
tr { backgroundColor: <whatever> }
tr.highlighted { backgroundColor: #dcfac9 }
```

Then your Javascript becomes

```
function ChangeColor(tableRow, highLight) {
    if(highLight) 
    {
        tableRow.className = 'highlighted';
    } 
    else 
    {
        tableRow.className = '';
    }
}
```

In addition to keeping specific styles out of your script *and* markup (where they become difficult to maintain over time), this lets you add or change hover styles (say, bold text, or a border) without adding complexity to the code.

If you have access to a Javascript library such as [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org), [Ext.js](http://extjs.com) or [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org), then you can use their class manipulation functions instead, which will handle the case where you want to preserve an existing className, or are using multiple classes for on a single element.

Comment: @Rick: I actually liked *yours* better - in my experience, putting raw style values in code is just asking for later headaches; your stylesheet suggestion is much preferable. I've merged the two for reference, edit as you see fit.

Comment: The first example has worked. I could swear I tried that before, but I guess not. Rick, Thank you for your help! And thank you Shog9!

Comment: @Shog9: I guess I liked yours better b/c it answered the question more directly.  I /do/ prefer using classes to handcoded styles, though.

Comment: Also directly changing the class name is not a good expertise since the object may have other classes attached to it. Using a function like "addClass" and "removeClass" will be a much better solution ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I recommended using a JS library to do class manipulation (since addClass and removeClass aren't built in to JS, AFAIK).